# get particular part of the table tag data using python

Tags: python, html, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have an html save in my local drive it consist of multiple table in it but i want to extract some specific table from whole page and export to csv. So i have wrote small script in python which gives me whole html text data now i have no idea how to extract data from these.

Python code -

```
import pandas as pd 
url = "table1.html"
tables = pd.read_html(url)[0]
print(tables)
```

The html files is -

```html
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?-->
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;" width="100%">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="border:none; padding: 0px;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;" width="100%">
                <tbody>
                    <tr style="height:70px">
                        <td style="width: 80%;border: none;background-color: #fb9895;color: White;font-weight: bold;font-size: 16px;height: 70px;vertical-align: bottom;padding: 0 0 17px 15px;font-family: Tahoma;">Backup job: MUMHOILNDDB01 Backup 1
                        <div class="jobDescription" style="margin-top: 5px;font-size: 12px;">&nbsp;</div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="border: none;padding: 0px;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;background-color: #fb9895;color: White;font-weight: bold;font-size: 16px;height: 70px;vertical-align: bottom;padding: 0 0 17px 15px;font-family: Tahoma;">Error
                        <div class="jobDescription" style="margin-top: 5px;font-size: 12px;">1 of 1 hosts processed</div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" style="border: none; padding: 0px;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="inner" style="margin: 0px;border-collapse: collapse;" width="100%">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr style="height: 17px;">
                                    <td class="sessionDetails" colspan="9" style="border-style: solid; border-color:#a7a9ac; border-width: 1px 1px 0 1px;height: 35px;background-color: #f3f4f4;font-size: 16px;vertical-align: middle;padding: 5px 0 0 15px;color: #626365; font-family: Tahoma;"><span>Tuesday, August 4, 2020 11:00:17 AM</span></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr style="height: 17px;">
                                    <td nowrap="nowrap" style="width: 1%;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Success</b></td>
                                    <td nowrap="nowrap" style="width:85px;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">0</td>
                                    <td nowrap="nowrap" style="width:85px;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Start time</b></td>
                                    <td nowrap="nowrap" style="width:85px;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">11:00:17 AM</td>
                                    <td nowrap="nowrap" style="width:85px;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Total size</b></td>
                                    <td nowrap="nowrap" style="width:85px;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">0 B</td>
                                    <td nowrap="nowrap" style="width:85px;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Backup size</b></td>
                                    <td nowrap="nowrap" style="width:85px;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">0 B</td>
                                    <td rowspan="3" style="border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;vertical-align: top;">&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr style="height: 17px;">
                                    <td nowrap="nowrap" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Warning</b></td>
                                    <td style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">0</td>
                                    <td nowrap="nowrap" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>End time</b></td>
                                    <td nowrap="nowrap" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">11:00:41 AM</td>
                                    <td nowrap="nowrap" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Data read</b></td>
                                    <td nowrap="nowrap" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">0 B</td>
                                    <td nowrap="nowrap" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Dedupe</b></td>
                                    <td nowrap="nowrap" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">1.0x</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr style="height: 17px;">
                                    <td nowrap="nowrap" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Error</b></td>
                                    <td style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">1</td>
                                    <td nowrap="nowrap" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Duration</b></td>
                                    <td nowrap="nowrap" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">0:00:24</td>
                                    <td nowrap="nowrap" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Transferred</b></td>
                                    <td nowrap="nowrap" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">0 B</td>
                                    <td nowrap="nowrap" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Compression</b></td>
                                    <td nowrap="nowrap" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">1.0x</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr style="height: 17px;">
                                    <td colspan="9" nowrap="nowrap" style="height: 35px;background-color: #f3f4f4;font-size: 16px;vertical-align: middle;padding: 5px 0 0 15px;color: #626365; font-family: Tahoma;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;">Details</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="processObjectsHeader" style="height: 23px">
                                    <td nowrap="nowrap" style="background-color: #e3e3e3;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;border-top: none;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Name</b></td>
                                    <td nowrap="nowrap" style="background-color: #e3e3e3;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;border-top: none;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Status</b></td>
                                    <td nowrap="nowrap" style="background-color: #e3e3e3;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;border-top: none;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Start time</b></td>
                                    <td nowrap="nowrap" style="background-color: #e3e3e3;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;border-top: none;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>End time</b></td>
                                    <td nowrap="nowrap" style="background-color: #e3e3e3;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;border-top: none;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Size</b></td>
                                    <td nowrap="nowrap" style="background-color: #e3e3e3;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;border-top: none;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Read</b></td>
                                    <td nowrap="nowrap" style="width:1%;background-color: #e3e3e3;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;border-top: none;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Transferred</b></td>
                                    <td nowrap="nowrap" style="background-color: #e3e3e3;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;border-top: none;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Duration</b></td>
                                    <td style="background-color: #e3e3e3;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;border-top: none;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Details</b></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr style="height: 17px;">
                                    <td nowrap="nowrap" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">MUMHOILNDDB01</td>
                                    <td nowrap="nowrap" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><span style="color: #FF0000;">Error</span></td>
                                    <td nowrap="nowrap" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">11:00:19 AM</td>
                                    <td nowrap="nowrap" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">11:00:41 AM</td>
                                    <td nowrap="nowrap" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">0 B</td>
                                    <td nowrap="nowrap" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">0 B</td>
                                    <td nowrap="nowrap" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">0 B</td>
                                    <td nowrap="nowrap" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">0:00:21</td>
                                    <td style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><span class="small_label" style="font-size: 10px;">Backup job has failed<br />
                                    Backup task has been failed<br />
                                    Processing finished with errors at 2020-08-04 11:00:42 GMT</span></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to export data with column Name,Start time,End time,Size,Read,   Transferred,Duration,Details

As the upper desired  data is present multiple times  in  html file so i want to get all the multiple data present in these column in html file. As the html file is bit complicated and i am new to these i don't know how to start.
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

```py
import pandas as pd


html = """
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><html><head><META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /></head><body><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;"><tr><td style="border:none; padding: 0px;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;"><tr style="height:70px"><td style="width: 80%;border: none;background-color: #fb9895;color: White;font-weight: bold;font-size: 16px;height: 70px;vertical-align: bottom;padding: 0 0 17px 15px;font-family: Tahoma;">Backup job: MUMHOILNDDB01 Backup 1 <div class="jobDescription" style="margin-top: 5px;font-size: 12px;"></div></td><td style="border: none;padding: 0px;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;background-color: #fb9895;color: White;font-weight: bold;font-size: 16px;height: 70px;vertical-align: bottom;padding: 0 0 17px 15px;font-family: Tahoma;">Error<div class="jobDescription" style="margin-top: 5px;font-size: 12px;">1
                        of
                        1
                            hosts processed
                          </div></td></tr><tr><td colspan="2" style="border: none; padding: 0px;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="inner" border="0" style="margin: 0px;border-collapse: collapse;"><tr style="height: 17px;"><td colspan="9" class="sessionDetails" style="border-style: solid; border-color:#a7a9ac; border-width: 1px 1px 0 1px;height: 35px;background-color: #f3f4f4;font-size: 16px;vertical-align: middle;padding: 5px 0 0 15px;color: #626365; font-family: Tahoma;"><span>Tuesday, August 4, 2020 11:00:17 AM</span></td></tr><tr style="height: 17px;"><td nowrap="" style="width: 1%;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Success</b></td><td nowrap="" style="width:85px;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">0</td><td nowrap="" style="width:85px;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Start time</b></td><td nowrap="" style="width:85px;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">11:00:17 AM</td><td nowrap="" style="width:85px;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Total size</b></td><td nowrap="" style="width:85px;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">0 B</td><td nowrap="" style="width:85px;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Backup size</b></td><td nowrap="" style="width:85px;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">0 B</td><td rowspan="3" style="border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;vertical-align: top;"><span class="small_label" style="font-size: 10px;"> </span></td></tr><tr style="height: 17px;"><td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Warning</b></td><td style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">0</td><td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>End time</b></td><td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">11:00:41 AM</td><td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Data read</b></td><td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">0 B</td><td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Dedupe</b></td><td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">1.0x</td></tr><tr style="height: 17px;"><td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Error</b></td><td style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">1</td><td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Duration</b></td><td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">0:00:24
</td><td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Transferred</b></td><td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">0 B</td><td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Compression</b></td><td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">1.0x</td></tr><tr style="height: 17px;"><td colspan="9" nowrap="" style="height: 35px;background-color: #f3f4f4;font-size: 16px;vertical-align: middle;padding: 5px 0 0 15px;color: #626365; font-family: Tahoma;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;">
                            Details
                          </td></tr><tr class="processObjectsHeader" style="height: 23px"><td nowrap="" style="background-color: #e3e3e3;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;border-top: none;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Name</b></td><td nowrap="" style="background-color: #e3e3e3;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;border-top: none;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Status</b></td><td nowrap="" style="background-color: #e3e3e3;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;border-top: none;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Start time</b></td><td nowrap="" style="background-color: #e3e3e3;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;border-top: none;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>End time</b></td><td nowrap="" style="background-color: #e3e3e3;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;border-top: none;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Size</b></td><td nowrap="" style="background-color: #e3e3e3;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;border-top: none;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Read</b></td><td nowrap="" style="width:1%;background-color: #e3e3e3;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;border-top: none;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Transferred</b></td><td nowrap="" style="background-color: #e3e3e3;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;border-top: none;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Duration</b></td><td style="background-color: #e3e3e3;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;border-top: none;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Details</b></td></tr><tr style="height: 17px;"><td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">MUMHOILNDDB01</td><td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><span style="color: #FF0000;">Error</span></td><td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">11:00:19 AM</td><td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">11:00:41 AM</td><td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">0 B</td><td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">0 B</td><td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">0 B</td><td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">0:00:21
</td><td style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><span class="small_label" style="font-size: 10px;">Backup job has failed<br />Backup task has been failed<br />Processing finished with errors at 2020-08-04 11:00:42 GMT</span></td></tr></table></td></tr></table>
"""

goal = pd.read_html(html)[2]
goal.to_csv("data.csv")
```

Note there's `3` tables there. so you can assign according to your choice.

Output: [view-online](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/09ea525da5357cf6090f8e11dd9c3928/data.csv)

[image]

Updated Answer:

```
import pandas as pd


html = """
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><html><head><META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /></head><body><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;"><tr><td style="border:none; padding: 0px;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;"><tr style="height:70px"><td style="width: 80%;border: none;background-color: #fb9895;color: White;font-weight: bold;font-size: 16px;height: 70px;vertical-align: bottom;padding: 0 0 17px 15px;font-family: Tahoma;">Backup job: MUMHOILNDDB01 Backup 1 <div class="jobDescription" style="margin-top: 5px;font-size: 12px;"></div></td><td style="border: none;padding: 0px;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;background-color: #fb9895;color: White;font-weight: bold;font-size: 16px;height: 70px;vertical-align: bottom;padding: 0 0 17px 15px;font-family: Tahoma;">Error<div class="jobDescription" style="margin-top: 5px;font-size: 12px;">1
                        of
                        1
                            hosts processed
                          </div></td></tr><tr><td colspan="2" style="border: none; padding: 0px;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="inner" border="0" style="margin: 0px;border-collapse: collapse;"><tr style="height: 17px;"><td colspan="9" class="sessionDetails" style="border-style: solid; border-color:#a7a9ac; border-width: 1px 1px 0 1px;height: 35px;background-color: #f3f4f4;font-size: 16px;vertical-align: middle;padding: 5px 0 0 15px;color: #626365; font-family: Tahoma;"><span>Tuesday, August 4, 2020 11:00:17 AM</span></td></tr><tr style="height: 17px;"><td nowrap="" style="width: 1%;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Success</b></td><td nowrap="" style="width:85px;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">0</td><td nowrap="" style="width:85px;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Start time</b></td><td nowrap="" style="width:85px;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">11:00:17 AM</td><td nowrap="" style="width:85px;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Total size</b></td><td nowrap="" style="width:85px;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">0 B</td><td nowrap="" style="width:85px;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Backup size</b></td><td nowrap="" style="width:85px;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">0 B</td><td rowspan="3" style="border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;vertical-align: top;"><span class="small_label" style="font-size: 10px;"> </span></td></tr><tr style="height: 17px;"><td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Warning</b></td><td style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">0</td><td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>End time</b></td><td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">11:00:41 AM</td><td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Data read</b></td><td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">0 B</td><td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Dedupe</b></td><td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">1.0x</td></tr><tr style="height: 17px;"><td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Error</b></td><td style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">1</td><td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Duration</b></td><td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">0:00:24
</td><td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Transferred</b></td><td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">0 B</td><td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Compression</b></td><td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">1.0x</td></tr><tr style="height: 17px;"><td colspan="9" nowrap="" style="height: 35px;background-color: #f3f4f4;font-size: 16px;vertical-align: middle;padding: 5px 0 0 15px;color: #626365; font-family: Tahoma;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;">
                            Details
                          </td></tr><tr class="processObjectsHeader" style="height: 23px"><td nowrap="" style="background-color: #e3e3e3;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;border-top: none;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Name</b></td><td nowrap="" style="background-color: #e3e3e3;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;border-top: none;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Status</b></td><td nowrap="" style="background-color: #e3e3e3;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;border-top: none;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Start time</b></td><td nowrap="" style="background-color: #e3e3e3;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;border-top: none;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>End time</b></td><td nowrap="" style="background-color: #e3e3e3;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;border-top: none;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Size</b></td><td nowrap="" style="background-color: #e3e3e3;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;border-top: none;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Read</b></td><td nowrap="" style="width:1%;background-color: #e3e3e3;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;border-top: none;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Transferred</b></td><td nowrap="" style="background-color: #e3e3e3;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;border-top: none;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Duration</b></td><td style="background-color: #e3e3e3;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;border-top: none;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Details</b></td></tr><tr style="height: 17px;"><td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">MUMHOILNDDB01</td><td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><span style="color: #FF0000;">Error</span></td><td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">11:00:19 AM</td><td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">11:00:41 AM</td><td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">0 B</td><td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">0 B</td><td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">0 B</td><td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">0:00:21
</td><td style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><span class="small_label" style="font-size: 10px;">Backup job has failed<br />Backup task has been failed<br />Processing finished with errors at 2020-08-04 11:00:42 GMT</span></td></tr></table></td></tr></table>
"""

goal = pd.read_html(html, skiprows=5, header=0)[0]
goal.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Output: [view-online](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/c6b22046d57e3b4e15f6656f61014e7f/data.csv)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! but i only want to export data Name,Status,Start time and Details as the image shows above in your example

Comment: i have edited my question these make easier to understand.Thank you !

Comment: Hey! Thank you for the answer. but my html file is in local directory i am passing it as a file and when i am running `goal = pd.read_html(html, skiprows=5, header=0)[0]
goal.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)` it does not give the desired answer as i have shown the small part of my html as the snippet but the html file is big and the there i multiple data in tag with Name,Status,StartTime etc. is there any work around for these?

Comment: @rohan you've received an answer based on what you've provided. that's why i highly advise you to check [ask]